# having correct dependencies for repository ruiles in bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to let a repository rule to be run again in bazel when files used by the rule changes.
I have the following rule

```
def _irule_impl(ctx):
    cmd = [ str(ctx.path(ctx.attr._tool)) ]
    st = ctx.execute(cmd, environment = ctx.os.environ)
    ctx.symlink(st.stdout,"my_r2")
    ctx.execute(["echo",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Running implementation"], quiet=False)

        "_tool_deps2": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            default = "//tools:tool3",
        ),
        "_tool_deps3": attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            default = "//tools:tool_filegroup",
        ),
    }
)
```

`//tools:tool3` is a file, and when I change that, the rule is executed again
`//tools:tools_filesgroup` is a filegroup

```
filegroup(
    name = "tool_filegroup",
    srcs = "tool2"
)
```

and when I change `tool2` the repository rule is not executed again when I build.
Is there a way to get this working ?